# I have a table view and I want to spread table cells with a gap

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I want to load a table view with cells. In between cells I should able to see minimum cell gap. How can I increase existing table view cell distance in my navigation controller root view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't increase cell distance, but what you can do is subclass UITableViewCell, override `-layoutSubviews`, and reposition all the internal views to allow for a bit of padding on one (or both) end(s) of the cell.

That said, I can't think of a single app on the iPhone that has a cell padding like this. You should think very carefully before doing this, as it's quite non-standard.

Comment: can    u help me how to add image to navigation bar or add image inplace of that ...

Comment: UIImage * buttonExampleImage = [UIImage  imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]   pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageName"]  ofType:@"png"]];
 
UIButton *buttonExmaple = [UIButton  buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];  
 
[buttonExmaple setImage:buttonExampleImage  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 
[buttonExmaple  addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonEvent:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  
 
  
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonExmaple;

Answer (score 0):

+1 you cant increase cell distance. However you can make it look that way: custom cells are easy to make in IB, and good custom cells are worth their weight in gold. You could set the cell spacer to none and a desired hight while making two UIImageViews (or a label with a cheeky string of underscores) in the cell to create the illusion of a cell boundary.

Here is a good tutorial on custom cells (I recommend watching the screen-cast):
http://icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/